# error:0906d06c:pem routines:pem_read_bio:no start line : Node red Raspberry pi google-action- node

Tags: raspberry-pi, node-red

I’m working on a raspberry pi and I secured my node red by watching this vid https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z9a_ztJqaII

I’m trying to use google action on my node red, and it required “SSL Certificate and SSL Privatekey” which should be in .crt and .key format I tried converting the Certificate.pem and privatekey.pem to .crt and .key respectively  but anytime I deploy my node I get this

```
{ error:0906d06c:pem routines:pem_read_bio:no start line }
```

Which I believe its because the node can’t read my .crt and .key files. I don’t know if anyone came across something like this or you have an idea on how I should go around it ?

I don’t know if I did the right thing but I used

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in certificate.pem -out certificate.crt
```

To convert my certificate.pem to certificate.crt and for the privatekey.pem I just changed the extension (from .pem to .key)

Comment: That openssl command will create DER formated output not PEM. What happens if you just use the original files

Comment: when I try using the original files the Node-REd keeps on crashing

Comment: I just figured out a way to go around it. the port I was using was 8081 and the node-red keeps crashing but I tried changing the port to 9091 and use the original .pem files and it works.

Comment: Edit the question to show the error message when it crashes